# Assign values of variables to a 2d Array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm sure it's a simple question, although i have trouble finding comprehensive explanation to it.
I am trying to fill 2d array with data which comes in form of variables from different places in order to later write in range. These variables change their values while looping through arrays of data. Consequently, at the end i get array populated only with latest values of these variables instead of the values they held at the moment i assigned the to positions in 2d array.

I vaguely understand that it has to do that I'm writing pointer to o memory slot (or something like that) into array instead of value, and it can be overcome by some evaluation or construction of new variable, but I can't find comprehensive explanation why/when it happens and what is the best way to tackle this problem.

So for example, i have code:

```
  var rowArray = [".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."];
  var rangeArray = [];
  for (k = 0; k < 5; k++){
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++){ 
      rowArray[i] = ((i+1) *(k+1));
    }
  rangeArray.push(rowArray);
  }
  Logger.log(rangeArray);
```

which gives output:
[[5.0, 10.0, 15.0, 20.0, 25.0, 30.0], [5.0, 10.0, 15.0, 20.0, 25.0, 30.0], [5.0, 10.0, 15.0, 20.0, 25.0, 30.0], [5.0, 10.0, 15.0, 20.0, 25.0, 30.0], [5.0, 10.0, 15.0, 20.0, 25.0, 30.0]]

instead of the one i wanted:
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12], [3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18], [4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24], [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30]]

I can overcome this problem by converting array to string and then constructing array from it.

```
  var rowArray = [".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."];
  var rangeArray = [];
  for (k = 0; k < 5; k++){
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++){ 
      rowArray[i] = ((i+1) *(k+1));
    }
  rangeArray.push(rowArray.toString().split(","));
  }
  Logger.log(rangeArray);
```

But it is a workaraound rather then a solution. Besides it would be very cumbersome and unreliable with real code where values of array entries may contain commas themselves.

So can you explain how to write current value of variable to an array instead of pointer to it?

Answer (score 0):

Declare the new modifiable array each time - inside the loop:

```js
  /*<ignore>*/console.config({maximize:true,timeStamps:false,autoScroll:false});/*</ignore>*/ 

  //Removed: var rowArray = [".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."];
  const rangeArray = [];
  for (k = 0; k < 5; k++){
    const rowArray = [];// or if you want [".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."];
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++){ 
      rowArray[i] = ((i+1) *(k+1));
    }
    rangeArray.push(rowArray);
  }
  console.log(rangeArray);
```

```html
<!-- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375985/ -->    <script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Also see other methods here: [Copy array by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copy-array-by-value)

Comment: Thank you! 
Your answer and the link to the post you provided gave me the comprehensive answer i needed.